# How can I toggle a class inside a button on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

What's the proper way to toggle a couple classes on click in jQuery?

1) HTML before click:

```
<button class="btn"><i class="icon-sign-blank"></i> Click me!</button>
```

2) HTML after click:

```
<button class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-check"></i> Clicked!</button>
```

3) HTML after another click: (same as beginning)

```
<button class="btn"><i class="icon-sign-blank"></i> Click me!</button>
```

Current jQuery:

```
$('btn').on('click',function(e) {
    $('btn > i').removeClass('icon-sign-blank').addClass('icon-check');
    $('btn').addClass('btn-success');
});
```

But this works once, but not back again.  What's the proper way to handle both directions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can - should - use toggleClass to manage it !

```
$('btn').on('click',function(e) {
    $('btn > i').toggleClass('icon-sign-blank icon-check');
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-success');
});
```

Comment: Just make sure no other code can modify those classes or they will be in an inconsistent state

Comment: And I'm just mentioning the unlikely case that this could break :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function.

Answer (score 0):

... and without using `toggleClass` (if you'd prefer not to use jQuery, this can be done without jQuery as well)

```
var btnEl = $('btn');
btnEl.on('click', function() {
    if (btnEl.hasClass('icon-sign-blank')) btnEl.removeClass('icon-sign-blank');
    else btnEl.addClass('icon-sign-blank');
});
```

Comment: Using .on is purely jQuery staff !

Comment: Indeed it is, that's why I said "if" you prefer not to use jQuery :). It's fairly trivial to rejigger the code to use addEventListener, etc.

Comment: @JulianH.Lam  No, it is not fairly trivial, there are lots of gotchas across browsers. If you're going to say this can be done without `jQuery`, please don't use `jQuery`. Even better, the question is tagged with `jQuery`, just use it.